# Automapper Mapping, inheritance from generic list

Tags: c#, automapper

```
    public class Flight {
        public CabinCollection Cabins { get; set; }
    }

    public class CabinCollection : List<Cabin>
    {
        public Cabin Lowest { set; get; }
    }
```

source and dest class have the same members

```
   1)  Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
        cfg.CreateMap<Domain.Flight, Contract.Flight>();
        cfg.CreateMap<Domain.Cabin, Contract.Cabin>();
    });

    List<Flight> res = Mapper.Map<List<Flight>>(flights);
```

It works but the member 'lowest' is null

```
   2)  Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<Domain.Flight, Contract.Flight>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Domain.Cabin, Contract.Cabin>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Domain.CabinCollection,Contract.CabinColection>
                .IncludeBase<List<Domain.Cabin>, List<Contract.Cabin>>()
        });
```

It works and the member 'lowest' mapped, but the list is null

Is there a way make it right?

Comment: This code should work without any additional configuration.

Comment: it did work but not return the expected result

Comment: @ShawnQian I am facing the same issue, do you have any idea to work with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your configuration

```
cfg.CreateMap<Domain.CabinCollection, Contract.CabinCollectionDest>();
```

Basically Automapper wouldn't know how to map `CabinCollection` object

[.Net fiddle link to show this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/buggPo)

Comment: This still won't map elements of `CabinCollection`, only lowest cabin. The destination list will be empty.