# Automapper fails to map from a custom model that inherits from a dictionary

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a model that inherits from **Dictionary<string, string>** and have 5 additional properties. These objects that inherit from Dictionary are part of a collection in two separate other models. When those two models are mapped, everything is fine except those 5 additional properties. How can those be mapped? I could not figure out a mapper configuration strategy for this...

Providing a dummy example below;

Below is my model;

```
public class MyModel : Dictionary<string, string> // All values in dictionary maps correctly
{
   public SomeObject Prop1 { get; set; } // Won't map
   public int Prop2 { get; set; } // Won't map
   public string Prop3 { get; set; } // Won't map
   public string Prop4 { get; set; } // Won't map
   public bool Prop5 { get; set; } // Won't map
}
```

Below are two other models that will be mapped to each other with automapper.

```
public class BaseObject : ICommonInterface
{
   public IList<MyModel> MyList { get; set; }

   public int Prop1 { get; set; } 
   public bool Prop2 { get; set; } 
}

public class TargetObject : ICommonInterface
{
   public IList<MyModel> MyList { get; set; } // MyModel properties values won't map, dictionary values map ok.

   public int Prop1 { get; set; } // Maps correctly
   public bool Prop2 { get; set; } // Maps correctly
}
```

I Map with below code; base model has 5 properties in MyModel List populated.

```
var model = new MyModel();
model["a"] = "some value"; // This maps ok
model["b"] = "some other value"; // This maps ok

model.Prop5 = true; // This will not be mapped in end result.

baseObject.MyList.Add(model);
_mapper.Map(baseObject, targetObject);
```

Comment: @John It might not, just wrote a dummy code for example

Comment: @John thanks fixed that part now

Comment: and why you are extending Dictionary instead having Dictionary as one of the properties?

Comment: Without digging into it, my guess is that it sees your object as a `Dictionary<string, string>` rather than as a specific mapped type. I'm not sure about the best solution to that besides not inheriting from `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Comment: @Selvin I use this for representing generic grid data rows for multi platform (Windows, WPF, ios, Android) use on grids, table views with additional properties supporting each row for certain capabilities. Columns and their numbers can change, their types can change. Satisfying some business requirements.

Comment: @John Thanks. If I use both object types the same, it does map though. BaseObject to another BaseObject maps correctly with those properties included..

Comment: I was asking why not have `MyModel { Dictionary<string, string> Data {get;set;} ... rest props }` instead ... or simply use `Dictionary<string, object>` instead and put all props there

Comment: @Selvin Right I see, well it was difficult to give capabilities to for each row and column individually at that time. Picked a solution like this. It's not just one or two reasons. Could have gone with the route **Dictionary<string, object>** instead, object could contain the individual capabilities with the actual value property as well, and that would bind to model.list.list[]. But went with the current way, it's easier to work with visually, at least for me, I couldn't find a disadvantage honestly.. Maybe this will be the first one after 3 years..

Comment: you know that Dictionary has 5 own props ... that's prolly authors of Automaper choose to map only data

Comment: @Selvin yes you are correct I think. Since they are different types of objects, perhaps automapper ignores it. My question above was that, I don't know the **configuration strategy** for a scenario like this. There are examples of manual configuration on their site about inherited members, though I don't know how to configure a child enumerable member that has custom objects in it. Even those custom objects are same type, I wouldn't mind doing a manual map config, just don't know how to.. https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html

Comment: You are not the first with this problem. Seems like author of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015032/automapper-mapping-inheritance-from-generic-list) still haven't found an answer.